# Find how many colors are needed to color all vertices

Tags: visual, graph-theory

In this puzzle you need to identify the `minimum` number of colors needed to color vertices such that no `two` adjacent vertices have the same color.

[image]

Here, **grey dots** indicate vertices :P (sorry for bad drawing). You can use any colors to solve this puzzle. Also, you can take any vertex as the starting vertex.

All the best :)

Comment: I suspect that this is a duplicate question, or at least "similar enough" to an existing question. For your sake though, my answer would be three or four, as the schlegel diagram of a dodecahedron can be coloured with three (see left image [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/FractionalColoring_1000.gif)—it's *slightly* different—you only need to change two vertices to a fourth colour to make it work.)

Comment: What did you use to build that diagram? :O

Comment: @ManojKumar Paint :P

Comment: @Hugh Sorry, i was not knowing that this question is already present somewhere :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Four colors are needed.
>
>  Example coloring using a [greedy algorithm](https://github.com/davanderlinden/Our_DM_Project/wiki/How-can-we-find-the-minimum-number-of-colors-to-properly-color-a-graph%3F-Greedy-Coloring-Algorithm):
>
>  [image]
>
>  It cannot be done with 3 since the [Moser Spindle](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%3E2%2C+1-%3E3%2C+2-%3E4%2C+2-%3E5%2C+3-%3E6%2C+4-%3E5%2C+5-%3E6%2C+4-%3E6%2C+1-%3E7%2C+3-%3E7%2C+6-%3E7) is a subgraph of this graph and it has a chromatic number of 4 (it has a minimum of 4 colors to color the vertices)
>
>  [image]

Comment: well explain :)