# How many different ways can you color the diagram?

Tags: visual, graph-theory

This question is a continuation of [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96474/find-how-many-colors-are-needed-to-color-all-vertices).

Here are nine squares, connected by lines.

[image]

Each square must be colored, and two squares connected by a line must be colored differently.

**Question 1.** What is the minimum number of colors required?

**Question 2.** How many different colorings are possible with the minimum number of colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's name the squares (nodes in a graph) as follows: $T$ is the top node, $L1, \dots, L4$ denote the four nodes on the left column (from top to bottom), and $R1, \dots, R4$ similarly for the right column.

#### Question 1

The answer is

> **3 colors.**

Reasoning:

> First, observe that $T, L3, L4$ form a triangle, so we'll need at least three colors.

> Then, excluding the node $T$, I noticed that the remaining graph of 8 nodes is a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) in disguise, so the 8 nodes can be colored with just two colors: color $L1, L3, R1, R3$ red, and $L2, L4, R2, R4$ blue.

> Finally, we can assign a third color to the remaining $T$ (say, green), completing the proof that the graph can be colored with exactly **3 colors**.

#### Question 2

The answer is

> the graph can be colored using 3 colors in **42 different ways**.

Reasoning:

> We can color the triangle $T, L3, L4$ using three colors in $3! = 6$ different ways. Then $R3$ is forced by the triangle $T, L4, R3$, and then $R4$ by $T, R3, R4$.

> Now assume $T$ is green, $L3, R3$ are red, and $L4, R4$ are blue. $L2$ and $R2$ can be either green or blue.

> If at least one of $L2$ and $R2$ is blue, both $L1$ and $R1$ are forced to be red (3 possibilities).

> If both $L2$ and $R2$ are green, all three neighbors of both $L1$ and $R1$ are green, giving two choices for each (4 possibilities).

> In total, the graph can be colored using three colors in $3! \times (3+4) = 42$ different ways.